# Remove the tabindex the google maps in my page

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to remove the tabindex the map on my page.
I used the code below but the tab passes through the markers on the map and the Google logo.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            mapOptions);

    //Remove o TAB do mapa
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
          var mapContent = (document.getElementById("map"));
          mapContent('a').attr('tabindex',-1);          
      });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building off Vasil's answer

```
google.maps.event.addListener(MAP, "tilesloaded", function(){
    [].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('#map a')).forEach(function(item) {
        item.setAttribute('tabindex','-1');
    });
})
```

[Here is it in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/xiondark2008/46xeu7gq/)

Comment: It worked for the map and the logo of Google, but the tab runs the markers on the map. The markers have as NAP ID can access them to remove the tabindex?

Comment: @csf I am not sure what you are asking. Are you asking how include map markers in the tabindex?

Comment: Sorry..I did not want browsing the TAB passed by infowindow markers of the route drawn on the map.

I decided to   directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressInfoWindows: true } );

Comment: Why use `[].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('#map a'))` instead of just `document.querySelectorAll('#map a')` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
[].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('#map a')).forEach(function(item) { 
   item.removeAttribute('tabindex'); 
});
```

Some like that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version for jquery, which also handles some new buttons google maps has introduced, and divs that can be tabbed to.

```
$('#map a,#map button,#map div').each( function (){$(this).attr('tabindex','-1');$(this).attr('aria-hidden','true'); });
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work with jQuery

First I added an event listener to map's "idle" event after my coordinate data has been loaded

```
this.map.addListener('idle', $.proxy(this._removeTabindex, this));
```

then in _removeTabindex function I added tabindex="-1" and aria-hidden="true" to all elements

```
_removeTabindex: function () {
    $('.gm-map').find('*').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('tabindex','-1');
        $(this).attr('aria-hidden','true');
    })
}
```