# Remove tabindex from google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, accessibility

I am trying to remove the tabindex from the all parts of the maps api, i have already tried the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531075/remove-the-tabindex-the-google-maps-in-my-page):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(MAP, "tilesloaded", function(){
    [].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('#map a')).forEach(function(item) {
        item.setAttribute('tabindex','-1');
    });
})
```

But it doesn't work, i am trying it on a simple map to then add to the application, so here is the simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 50%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <input type="text">
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }         
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your map not to be interactive, it seems that using the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/) would be a reasonable choice

EDIT: According to your comment, if you wan't it to be fully functionnal for non screenreader users, you have the option to insert the map in a `<div aria-hidden="true">` tag which should disable the screenreader to read it. You can also add a "skip map" link above the map to let keyboard user (without screenreader) bypass the map.

Comment: I want it fully functional, the only thing that bothers me is that tabbing through the embedded maps takes a long time, since there are a lot of things that are focusable on it.

Comment: The only things that worked were either the skip map button or setting the tabindex of everything else to 1