# How to skip the tabIndex from google map div and move from one input to the other using angular8

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

i have 2 input fields along with the Map div, here when i tab over, the tab focus is going from first input field to the names and links inside map and after passing to all the map names it comes to the 2nd input field.
I have tried using making tabindex as -1, inside the map function but nothing worked.

Can anyone help me out, how to make this work.

TS:

```
 var map = new window["google"].maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
        center: { lat: 37.1587963, lng: -100.5623315 },
        zoom: 2
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, "titlesLoaded", function() {
        [].slice.apply(this.gmapElement.nativeElement).forEach(function(item) {
          item.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
        });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="col" >
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1">View on Map</a>
            <div  style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;width:100%;height:400px" #mapRef>
            </div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tujctc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: There is no map showing in your demo.

Comment: Thanks for response, just change something in code and revert back or fork it again map shows

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531075/remove-the-tabindex-the-google-maps-in-my-page

Comment: Alternatively, if you provide `tabindex="1"` in you first input, and `tabindex="2"` in your second input, it works as expected. I would prefer this solution, rather than using scripts to modify the behavior of the map components.

Comment: Thanks for response, can you edit in my demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, you can simply add `tabindex="1"` and `tabindex="2"` on your 2 inputs.

Working code snippet:

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  // Create the map and center on deault location
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 3
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<input type="text" tabindex="1">

<div id="map"></div>

<input type="text" tabindex="2">

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```